# Invalid json_encode output

Tags: php, json, mysqli

Starting a new project, and I've come upon a hitch moving from deprecated mysql_query commands to the new mysqli type arguments.

The code is as follows:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "dbname");

// Check the connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed.");
    exit();
}

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM SafariFinder_Directory");

while ($rows = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo json_encode($rows);
}

echo $res;

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

This gets me the following output:

```
{"id":"3","inGameName":"Syrinathos","friendCode":"0000 0000 0000","safariType":"Normal","safariSlot1":"Aipom","safariSlot2":"Kecleon","safariSlot3":""}
{"id":"2","inGameName":"Herschel","friendCode":"1234 12341 234","safariType":"Zombie","safariSlot1":"Crawler","safariSlot2":"Runner","safariSlot3":""}
{"id":"4","inGameName":"Syrinathos","friendCode":"0000 0000 0000","safariType":"Normal","safariSlot1":"Aipom","safariSlot2":"Kecleon","safariSlot3":"Ditto"}
{"id":"6","inGameName":"Kira","friendCode":"2345 2345 2345","safariType":"Ghost","safariSlot1":"Shuppet","safariSlot2":"Haunter","safariSlot3":"Gengar"}
```

The only components it's missing to be valid JSON are the square brackets and the commas between the actual entries. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should be obvious why there's no square brackets and as a whole it's invalid json; you can't dump chunks of json in serial with nothing in between and obtain valid json as a whole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the result into an array, then encode the array.

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: And that's the kind of simple fix I've come to know and love.